# How to get Object type bound to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that is bound to ObservableCollection.

What I am wondering is: without resorting to looking at an item and retrieving the object type, can I somehow use the actual DataGrid object and the ItemSource to find the type of objects?

So if I have the following:

```
DataGrid dg = DataGridObject as DataGrid;
Console.WriteLine("binding5=" + dg.ItemsSource.GetType());



output = System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[UserManagement.UserViewModel]
```

Can I extract `UserManagement.UserViewModel` into an object variable somehow

Comment: The question author said *without resorting to looking at an item and retrieving the object type*... bearing that in mind @Sajeetharan, can you explain how a `foreach` loop would help?

Comment: @Sheridan You are right , i dint read the question completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find out the type of object *inside* the collection that is set as the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property. To do this, you can use some basic reflection. Try this:

```
var collection = ListBox.ItemsSource;
Type collectionType = collection.GetType();
Type itemType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
```

Comment: This solution won't works for me it gives me an exception that `sequence contains no element`

Comment: @abdou93, perhaps you didn't set the `ItemsSource`? If you added items to the `Items` collection instead, then you replace the first line of my solution with: `var collection = ListBox.Items;`. If you did neither, then you have no items to check.

Comment: No, my ItemsSource is filled with items .

Comment: The **sequence contains no element** error is raised when you try to access items from a empty collection, so I'm not sure what you're doing. If you have access to the data bound collection, then you can query that directly, in the same way as above.

Answer (score 1):

with assumption that the collection is of type `ObservableCollection<>`

here you go

```
        Type collectionType = dg.ItemsSource.GetType();

        if (collectionType.IsGenericType && collectionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ObservableCollection<>)))
        {
            Type objType = collectionType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        }
```

here we will confirm if the type is a generic type and its generic definition is assignable from `ObservableCollection<>` then will take the first type argument which will be the type of elements