# How to get List of Properities from System.Collections.IEnumerable using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, itemssource

I need to fetch the List of Model Class Properties using System.Collections.IEnumerable of a DataGrid Control in WPF.

DataGrid Control has a Property `public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }`

Consider the ItemsSource is assigned with the following List: `List<Person> EmpList`

```
void Main()
{
    List<Person> EmpList = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() {ID = 101, Name = "Peter", Gender = "Male", Role = "Manager"},
        new Person() {ID = 102, Name = "Emma Watson", Gender = "Female", Role = "Assistant"},
        new Person() {ID = 103, Name = "Kaliya", Gender = "Manager", Role = "Assistant"},
    };
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

I need to fetch the Properties name using `public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }`

I tried it by using `List<Person> EmpList`

```
EmpList.GetType()
    .GetInterfaces()
    .Where(t => t.IsGenericType == true
        && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0])
    .FirstOrDefault().GetProperties()
    .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

The output of the above Query is

[image]

as like this I need to fetch the model Properties using **DataGrid ItemsSource**

I tried it using `this.ItemsSource` within the Datagrid Control Class, but I can't able to fetch the List. But the ItemsSource is filled with 3 collection as identical with the above collection.

```
this.ItemsSource.GetType()
    .GetInterfaces()
    .Where(t => t.IsGenericType == true
        && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0])
    .FirstOrDefault().GetProperties()
    .Select(x => x.Name).ToList().Dump();
```

I need the same output as mentioned in above using `this.ItemsSource`. Kindly assist me how to achieve this???

I tried @bhuvin approach - **Reflection**, but I got the empty result

**Screen Shot 1**: The ItemsSource is Loaded Properly with List
[image]

**Screen Shot 2**: I got empty set of Result
[image]

Type Info and Property Info Step By Step Snap Shots

Type Info:

[image]

Property Info:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.Reflection;  // reflection namespace

    // get all public static properties of ObjList's type
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
    //objList might be any type of Collection.
    propertyInfos = objList.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Static);
    // sort properties by name
    Array.Sort(propertyInfos,
            delegate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
            { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });

    // write property names
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know the Class Name. How to achieve this. Because in DataGrid we just pass the collection. Then how Could I achieve this? Kindly explain me please...

Comment: @IRPunch : try this one. This is a Generic idea. you gotta implement it relevant to you.

Comment: I apexes the Screen shots in my post. Kindly refer it. I got a empty sets... Kindly assist me

Comment: @IRPunch : could you just attach a Screen shot of :
1. The Type returned by the GetType() call.
2. What does GetProperties() result ?

Comment: Kindly refer the post, I edited with the Screen shots as per your queries.

Comment: @IRPunch :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670990/how-to-get-object-type-bound-to-datagrid

Comment: Here the issue is I can't able to get the Properties Information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107694/discussion-between-bhuvin-and-ir-punch).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that PersonsGrid is the name of the Datagrid control the following code should return the required data:

```
Type itemType = PersonsGrid.ItemsSource.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

var propertyNames = itemType.GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: It returns empty set of string.